# Broadcasting message from ipcMain in electron

Tags: electron

I need to broadcast a message from main process of electron to all renderer processes. There is no send option for [ipcMain](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/ipc-main/), only an option to reply to the sender via `event.sender.send()`.

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for the `webContents` API. From the same page of documentation in your post:

> It is also possible to send messages from the main process to the renderer process, see webContents.send for more information.

Here is the doc for [webContents](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/web-contents)

Answer (score 2):

You could make an array of windows, then iterate over them and send a message to each one:

```js
var windowsArr = [];

windowsArr.push(new BrowserWindow({title: "Win 1"}));
windowsArr.push(new BrowserWindow({title: "Win 2"}));

function broadcast (message) {
    for (var i = 0; i < windowsArr.length; i++) {
        windowsArr[i].webContents.send('asynchronous-message', message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on @Joshua's answers

in your main.js you can add something like that

```js
const {BrowserWindow, ipcMain} = require("electron")

// list of active windows
const windows = []

// method to create windows in your app
const createWindow = (fileToLoad) => {
    const win = new BrowserWindow({
        webPreferences: {
            preload: path.join(__dirname, "preload.js"),
        },
    })
    // add new window to list of active windows
    windows.push(win)
    // automatically remove window from list when closed
    win.on("closed", () => {
        const winId = windows.indexOf(win)
        winId > -1 && windows.splice(winId,1)
    })
    fileToLoad && win.loadFile(fileToLoad)
    return win
}

// broadcast to all windows opened with createWindow
const broadcast = (eventType, ...params) => {
    windows.forEach(win => win.webContents.send("app:broadcastEvent", {eventType, eventData: [...params]}))
}

// later in your code 
broadcast('customEvent', "parameter1", "parameter2")
```

in your preload.js you should expose a method to regiseter a listener for broadcasted events

```js
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require("electron")

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('electronAPI', {
    onBroadCastedEvent: (callback) => {
        ipcRenderer.on("app:broadcastEvent", (evt, {eventType, eventData}) => callback(eventType, ...eventData))
    }
})
```

then in you renderer.js you can register a listener like this:

```js
window.electronAPI.onBroadCastedEvent((eventType, ...eventParams) => {
    console.log(`received broadcast event ${eventType} with data: `, eventParams)
})
```