# Broadcasting events from main process to all renderer process electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I know how to send events from renderer process to main process using `ipcRenderer.send()` and `ipcMain.on()`. I could also send reply back to renderer process using `event.sender.send()` but got stuck on how can I send events from main process to all renderer process, more like a broadcast.

Comment: This question has been asked just one hour before you did: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44126768/broadcasting-message-from-ipcmain-in-electron/44134535#44134535. It should help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Broadcasting message from ipcMain in electron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44126768/broadcasting-message-from-ipcmain-in-electron)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create array of references to BrowserWindow instances and when global event is necessary you can map it with sender function, like this for example:

```
let windows = [];

let backgroundComputation = new BrowserWindow(options);
let webInteractions = new BrowserWindow(different_options);
let imageProcessing = new BrowserWindow(another_options);

windows.push(backgroundComputation)
windows.push(webInteractions)
windows.push(imageProcessing)

let sender = (message, windows) => 
        windows.map((ref) => ref.webContents.send('event_name', message))
```

This will probably be handy if you have whole bunch of them. You can also set flag in options `alwaysOnTop:true` to true for window on top so any other window will stay underneath. Hope this helps!